# querying excel spreadsheet in VBA using sql

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to query an excel file from VBA using SQL queries; I am working on a windows 7 machine 64 bit with office 2007 installed. I am using the connection string below [taken from here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/xlsm-files/)

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\TradeLogSettings.xlsm;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;
```

However when I try to open the connection as follow

```
'ConnDbString is the above connection string
If (Glob_Conn.State = 0) Then
      Glob_Conn.Open (ConnDbString)
End If
```

I get the error as per the attached screenshot

any idea about what I am doing wrong with the connection string ?

## error on Glob_Conn.Open

[image: VBA error]

**UPDATE 1**

The solution that I found is to use this connection string

```
Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm,*.xlsb)};DBQ=C:\TradeLogSettings.xlsm
```

if anyone knows a better connection string for my purpose is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the quotation marks are missing. Try this.
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\TradeLogSettings.xlsm;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";

Comment: Sorry to hear it. Some time ago this tutorial helped me. https://youtu.be/L0I24NGrUtc

Comment: now today the string that was working up to yesterday afternoon  Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & WorkBookPath is not working this morning; instead the one was not working yesterday  Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & WorkBookPath & ";" & ExcelExtendedProperties is working today !! There is something that i need to know about excel connection strings stability ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is to use this connection string

```
Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm,*.xlsb)};DBQ=C:\TradeLogSettings.xlsm
```